# Visual Studio Express with Visual Studio Ultimate installation

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010, windows-installation

Has anyone installed Visual C# Express 2010 in the same (Win 7 x64) machine which has Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 already installed ?

Note: This needs to be done for educational purposes as the menus and the right click options are different.

Comment: Install Express in a virtual environment. If you are using Win 7 Pro, check out XP Mode.

Comment: There should be no problem, just choose another place on your Computer to install Express.